# how to decrease value in database in mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table called `Table_Books` and I keep the number of books for each book as `int`. When user rents a book, I want to decrease the quantity of books in database. When it's 0 , a warning should appear like 'You can't rent this book'. How can I do this?

My "Rent a Book" method (even though it decreases, nothing changes in database):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RentBook(Table_Books book)
{
        User data = TempData["userdata"] as User ;

        if (data == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "error!";
            return RedirectToAction("index", "login");
        }
        else
        {
            Table_RentedBooks = new Table_RentedBooks ();
           
            var tbookid = book.BookID;
            var numberofbooks1=book.NumberofBooks-1;
            book.NumberofBooks= numberofbooks1;
            bookrepo.Update(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
          
            DateTime d1= DateTime.Now;
            DateTime recorddate= d1;
            DateTime deliverydate= d1.AddDays(14);

            z.DeliveryDate = deliverydate;
            z.RecordDate = recorddate;
            z.UserID = data.UserID;
            z.BookID = tbookid;
            
            rentedrepo.Add(z);
        
            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
        }
}
```

My repository methods

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T:class,new()
{
    LibraryEntities db = new LibraryEntities();

    public List<T> List()
    {
        return db.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void Add(T par)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Add(par);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(T par)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T TGet(int id)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public T Find(Expression<Func<T,bool>> where)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(where);
    }

    public void Delete(T par)
    {
        db.Set<T>().Remove(par);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibraryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\Local;initial catalog=Library;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: As a note, rather than, when you go to `UPDATE` you check the value of `quantity`, it makes more sense to have a `CONSTRAINT` on the column that doesn't allow the quantity to be `< 0`. Then, when there are `0` left, an attempt to `UPDATE` the value to `-1` would occur, and fail. Then you can parse a more meaningful error to the presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu ok i'll change it but still don't understand why update is not working. What am I missing in this code ?

Comment: What is your connection string?  Please show a redacted version. (A very common problem is that the database is in AppData and gets generated new every time the Application runs)

Comment: @Larnu If OP has NumberOfBooks already, as would appear to be the case from the code, then it would be wise to check that the number is greater than zero before attempting the update.  The DB `CONSTRAINT` can be a fall-back in the event of concurrency issues, but it is sensible to obviate a call to the DB, if you reasonably expect it to fail.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock My database is in web.config , the appdata folder is empty. I'm adding the connection string code in edit. (Sorry maybe it's not necessary but I'm new to MVC)

Comment: @JonathanWillcock if there is one left, then you would be able to still rent the book, there is one left. Of course, if you were to check the value first too, you would ned to ensure that you lock that row before you attempt to `UPDATE` it; otherwise, you could *easily* have race conditions: Transaction A checks value; gets 1. Transaction B checks value, gets 1 (row is not locked). Transaction A updates value to `value - 1`: `0`. Transaction B updates value to `value - 1`: `-1`.

Comment: @vives ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM like EF or a data access library like ADO.NET. The code you posted is *very* bad because it breaks EF's transaction behavior. A DbContex already is a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. A DbSet already is a single-entity repository. All this code simply prevents DbContext from acting as a UoW, by persisting all changes instead of caching them until they need to be committed.

Comment: @vives: you definitely need a transaction over the code, otherwise two or more concurrent users would still make your number of books negative.

Comment: @vives as for the question itself, the answer is to NOT use an ORM for this. The query `UPDATE Books SET Available=Available-1 Where BookId=@bookId` is the fastest, safest and most scalable way to decrease a field. There's no chance you'd save an incorrect value, even if multiple people tried to rent the same book. Only a single row is locked and then only for the duration of the update

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Where should I write this query?

Comment: @Larnu I think you misunderstood me.  I  meant check that NumberOfBooks is > zero before attempting the update.  Ie if greater than zero,then try update, if not, don't bother.

Comment: You'd still need that transaction though, @JonathanWillcock .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your data is not changing is that you are modifing the book that you got from your post request and your DbContext has no track of it. there are 2 solutions:

1.You can retrive the book from dbContext first and then modify it and call saveChange()

2.You should change the state of the entity to modified before you saveChanges. Somthing like this:

```
public void Update(T par)
{
    db.Entry(book).State = 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: In both cases there's a risk of storing the wrong value, because someone else rented the same book at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't EntityFramework handle concurrency on update by default?

Comment: I get System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.' error in SaveChanges part. My NumberofBooks column is nullable

Comment: I used try-catch to see what's missing and I fixed the problem. This works really well now , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Despite what you say about the AppData folder being empty, given your connectionString I am pretty sure that your data is being regenerated. Take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16).  of particular relevance is:

> The LocalDB setup program uses the SqlLocalDB.msi program to install
> the necessary files on the computer. Once installed, LocalDB is an
> instance of SQL Server Express that can create and open SQL Server
> databases. The system database files for the database are stored in
> the local AppData path, which is normally hidden. For example,
> C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
> DB\Instances\LocalDBApp1. User database files are stored where the
> user designates, typically somewhere in the C:\Users<user>\Documents
> folder.